# Change settings for Scrapy CrawlerRunner

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to change the settings for Scrapy. I've managed to successfully do this for CrawlerProcess before. But I can't seem to get it to work for CrawlerRunner. The log should be disabled but I'm still seeing output from the log. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
import scrapy
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.settings import Settings


class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider1"


class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider2"


configure_logging()

s = get_project_settings()

s.update({
    "LOG_ENABLED": "False"
})

runner = CrawlerRunner(s)


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider1)
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider2)
    reactor.stop()


crawl()

reactor.run()
```

Comment: _"But I can't seem to get it to work for CrawlerRunner"_ What is actually happening? What are you seeing? What are you expecting instead?

Comment: The log's not disabled. When log_enabled is set to false there should be no log message.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: What version of Scrapy are  you using? Passing `"False"` as a string to say `False` is supported only from Scrapy 1.3.1. Does it change anything if you do `"LOG_ENABLED": False`?

Comment: I've tried both "False" and False, neither works.

Comment: What happens when you do not call `configure_logging()`?

Comment: Damn I can't believe I missed that, I just copied an example from the scrapy site without checking what configure_logging() was doing. I just assumed the update code would override any previous settings. Thanks Paul, that's fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process), and the [api](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#scrapy.utils.log.configure_logging), you should use your `setting` to init the logger, so you should adjust your code like that:

```
# comment that line
# configure_logging()

s = get_project_settings()

s.update({
    "LOG_ENABLED": "False"
})

# init the logger using setting
configure_logging(s)

runner = CrawlerRunner(s)
```

Then you will get what you want.